# Using Function Library to Call browser

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

When I call on my action page to open the browser, it does open it and then it closes it. And then opens it again and then closes it repeatedly. I checked my function library but cannot seem to figure out why it does it. I am using Keyword driven framework.

I tried re writing the code and also commenting out the closing browser part but even then it closes it and opens repeatedly.

Here is my function library  to open the browser  and as well as another procedure to close browser

'Open application'

```
   Function OpenApp(AppName)
   If Browser("title:=.*").Exist Then
   Browser("title:=.*").CloseAllTabs
   End If

   systemutil.Run AppName
   wait(5)

  End Function
```

'Close application'

```
  Function CloseApp()
  Browser("title:=.*").CloseAllTabs
  wait(3)
  End Function
```

And Here is how I am calling it the browser in action, from my excel sheet.

```
 If ActionKey = "OpenApp" Then
 Call OpenApp(Obj_value)
 End If
```

I want the code to open the browser and keep it opened so I can perform other actions.

Comment: Is any data present in the Global Sheet? If yes, how many rows of data is present?

Comment: Hi i do not see any data resent in global sheet when I use breakpoints. I created new sheets. Here is my script for the import          

datatable.AddSheet "TS_UFT"
datatable.AddSheet "TestSteps_UFT"

datatable.ImportSheet FileLocation, "TestScenarios", "TS_UFT"
datatable.ImportSheet FileLocation, "TestSteps", "TestSteps_UFT"